# object property in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

```
@interface Category : NSObject

@property(nonatomic) NSInteger ID;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *Name;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *Description;

@end
```

product class

```
@interface Product : NSObject

@property(nonatomic) NSInteger ID;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *Name;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *Description;
```

> @property(nonatomic, retain) Category *category;

```
@end
```

How do I create a property of type Category. Is it possible at all?

Comment: If you would simply try running the code I think you'd find that it is. Maybe you need to add `#import "Category.h"` at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you class `Product` is defined in separate file, then:

```
#import "Category.h" // file, where class Category is defined

@interface Product : NSObject

@property(nonatomic) NSInteger ID;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *Name;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *Description;
@property(nonatomic, retain) Category *category;

@end
```

2) If your classes `Product` and `Category` are defined in same file then you don't need any additional `import` but be sure that class `Categiry` is defineed earlier then `Product`.

3) In the case when two classes have objects of type of each other then your should use `@class` tag:

```
@class Product;

@interface Category : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, retain) Product *product;
@end

@interface Product : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, retain) Category *category;
@end
```

Answer (score 3):

You do it just like you have, except you need to add a forward declaration of your Category class in Product.h (before your @interface line):

```
@Class Category;
```

And then import the header in Product.m

```
#import "Category.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, and the syntax that you have posted is correct.  If you are having a problem, perhaps it may be because you need to do

```
#import "Category.h"
```

at the top of Product.h, and you will need to make sure to `@synthesize` category.  But since you have been using other properties, I assume you knew that already.